# json error on specific file name dojo

Tags: json, dojo

**Javascript**

```
ready(function(){
         request.get("json/pie7.json", {
             // Parse data from JSON to a JavaScript object
             handleAs: "json"
         }).then(function(data){
             arrayUtil.forEach(data.items, function(item,i){
                itemArray.push(item.value);
             });
                alert(itemArray)
         },
         function(error){
            alert(error);
         });

});
```

**pie7.json**

```
{
    "title":"JSON Sample Data",
    "items":[{
        "name":"text",
        "value":33
    },{
        "name":"integer",
        "value":100
    },{
        "name":"float",
        "value":5.65
    },{
        "name":"boolean",
        "value":56
    }]
}
```

This shows error as:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'
```

But when I rename `pie7.json` to any file name such as `sample.json` and change the request path of javascript to the same name, then it works with no problem.
So Why am I getting error when I put the filename to pie7.json?

Comment: I doubt you're telling the whole story here. Did you try watching the network tab in a browser debugger (firebug, chrome's dev tools etc.) when the fetch was happening? Did the server response look correct at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that pie7.json is cached by your browser.  You can add `preventCache: true` to the request object to prevent caching.

```
request.get("json/pie7.json", {     
    handleAs: "json",
    preventCache: true
})
```